# Android Button Disable and enable

Tags: android

Hello I have an android application i want to create something like a lock button to the prevent error click on any button in application i use this method and it work great in disable all button i like but i can not re-enable it again after this all i need is that when i press lock button again it re-enable `button2` and button 3 again

**This is the activity code**

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
public class AboutActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        addListenerOnButton();
}
    Button button;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lock);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              button2.setEnabled(false);  //button which u want to disable
              button3.setEnabled(false);  //button which u want to disable
            }
        });
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.about, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**This is layout code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.lock.AboutActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lock"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use isEnabled() and use "not" operator to lock and unlock. If it's not enabled, it'll enable and vice versa.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              button2.setEnabled(!button2.isEnabled());  //button which u want to disable
              button3.setEnabled(!button3.isEnabled());  //button which u want to disable
            }
        });
```